Calculate the number of times groupings of three zeros (0's) appear in a row
I tried using the "Countifs" (Google Measure) ...but, I'm hoping there's a simple(r) way to "Look"  ...at:

rows of zeros (0's) ...and
determine how many times three (3) zeros appear [together]
see Google Sheet - below ⤵️

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BjMWeSzq2D7RjqEtNJs-emNdcv38PdYETsJWZDVfftQ/edit?gid=2100307022#gid=2100307022
Explained:

Employee A ...has 4 instances (over 18 weeks)
Employee B ...has 2 instances (over 18 weeks)
Employee C ...has 6 instances (over 18 weeks)
Employee D ...has 4 instances (over 18 weeks)



That will require a custom function. There are no functions that would be capable of doing such a feat on itself. The COUNTIF() will not easily check whether 3 zeroes are in a row. Just a grand total. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Here's a more traditional method of counting consecutive occurrences of a certain character:
=ArrayFormula(byrow(B2:S,lambda(r,if(counta(r),let(isZero,r&""="0",cols,column(B2:S),sum(quotient(frequency(if(isZero,cols),if(not(isZero),cols)),3))),))))

where the column numbers of cells which don't contain a zero mark out the bin ranges, while the column numbers of cells which do contain a zero are the data to be counted.

The first time I became aware of this method was way back in 2015, in this answer which contains a more detailed explanation.


Here's one approach you may test out:
=byrow(B2:S,lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,len(regexreplace(regexreplace(join(,Σ),"0{3}","Λ"),"[^Λ]",)))))



the formula assumes there will be no blank cells in a given row of 18 weeks

Modified formula if there's gonna be empty cells:
=byrow(B2:S,lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,len(regexreplace(regexreplace(join(,switch(Σ,"","x",Σ)),"0{3}","Λ"),"[^Λ]",)))))



Wow @rockinfreakshow ...you've done it again (and again) ☑️
Wanting to understand what was meant by "no blank cells" (in your post) - I replaced "x" (in the Google Sheet) ...with blank (Row 3, Employee B) ...and the count/formula (still) works - so, your formula is very POWERFUL

I mean like a scenario where say 3 cells (D5:F5) are empty & rest are filled as-is... Added alternate formula version above to cover that scenario just in case!

Another solution:
=BYROW(B2:S,LAMBDA(r,IF(COUNTA(r)=0,,LEN(REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(,SWITCH(r,"",1,r)),"(0)00|.","$1")))))



This is another solution, enter the below formula in a cell, say Y2 and drag down.
=LET(x,TEXTJOIN("",true,B2:S2),(len(x)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(x,"000","")))/3)

